Spread operator and typing
Why is this valid:
type A = {
    a: string;
};

function withA(a: A) {}

const test = (message: {b: number}) => {
    withA({
        ...message, // this
        a: 'foo',
    });
};

and this is valid:
type A = {
    a: string;
};

function withA(a: A) {}

const test = <T>(message: T) => {
    withA({
        ...message,
        b: 'bar', // this
        a: 'foo',
    });
};

I don't understand why using the spread operator makes this possible.
I tried reading documentation about structural typing and exact types but I can't find a precise answer.
Edit: My real question is why we have no warning here, like
"Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'A'". If I remove the spread line I do have a warning

Could you also include what you think the result should be and why? It would help us identify your mis-understanding.

Sorry maybe it wasn't clear enough. I don't understand why I have no warning here. Like "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'A'"

Are you expecting excess property checks? They only apply to a fairly narrow range of cases - your objects do satisfy the required interface.

If I remove the spread line then I have a warning, why?

TS version? Compiler settings? I can't repro - there is an error for b: Playground Link

Is one of those "valid"s supposed to be "invalid"? It's hard to understand what you might be asking without describing exactly the errors you see or expect to see and where they happen. One of the // this gives you an error and the other doesn't. Is that the confusing thing? If so then maybe you meant "invalid" in the first example. Could you [edit] to make it clear?

TypeScript uses structural type - meaning an object is the same type if it has at least the object type structure
so as log as you pass to type A an object that contains the property a: string - it will be valid
in both examples above you are passing a: string along with more fields.

this is regardless of the use of ... spread.

if you want type A to be more strict, you will have to define a custom type
